# Haskell: How to get the type of a data type with multiple parameters (like `Path a b = ..`

Tags: haskell

I have a data type like

```
Path a b = ...
```

with two data types for a and b (all of these have deriving (Typeable)). There is a value

```
p = ... : Path A B
```

and I need the type of `p`. I tried

```
t = typeRep p
```

but obtain only the last type parameter (i.e. B). Is there a way to get the full type parameter, i.e. `Path A B`?

Comment: What do you mean by `... : Path A B`? Do you mean that `p` is of type `Path A B`, in which case it would be `... :: Path A B`? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `typeOf` instead of `typeRep`. Compare:

```
typeOf  :: Typeable a =>       a -> TypeRep
typeRep :: Typeable a => proxy a -> TypeRep
```

Comment: Thank you. I was obviously confused by the explanation under `typeOf` which reads `Observe a type representation for the type of a value.` and is technically correct. Then I picked the function on the next line. Stupid me!

Comment: @user855443: The problem was that it was unifying `proxy a ~ (Path A) B`, giving `proxy ~ Path A` and `a ~ B`, so naturally you got the `TypeRep` for `B`. `proxy` is ordinarily intended to be instantiated with something like `Data.Proxy.Proxy`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. `typeOf` is the better choice and obviously easier to use in my case.